# Expect is failing but test is passing in cy.on confirm & alert message

Tags: cypress

I wanted to test my content of the confirmation message but it seems that even if my test fails my case passes

```
it('Should Get Confirm Message', () => {
        cy.get('.button')
            .click();
        cy.on('window:confirm', str => {
            expect(2 + 2).to.equal(5);
        })
    })
```

[Image of my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13xC8.png)

Comment: which version of cypress are you using? may be worth to update the latest one

Comment: Using the Latest one

Comment: It does not seem to be favoured in Cypress tests, but you might find it easiest to pass Mocha's done callback `it('Should Get Confirm Message', (done) => {` and call it after your expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually can't reproduce this, but Cypress events are generally considered to be outside the regular test flow (the `cy.on(eventName)` is not a command, despite the method being on the `cy` object, and so it's not added to the Command queue and isn't properly awaited).

What this means is that the `window:confirm` may be invoked after the test has already finished (which seems to be your case --- perhaps the click handler calls the `window.confirm` asynchronously?).

The expectation still bubbles through to (and is displayed in) the Command log, but it has no effect on the test outcome.

One thing you can do is to await the event using a proper command flow:

```js
describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {

    const confirmMessage = 'oi!';

    // (1) setup (for demonstration only)
    // -------------------------------------------------------

    cy.window().then(win => {
      win.document.body.innerHTML = '<button class="btn">Click me</button>';
      win.document.body.querySelector('.btn')
        .addEventListener('click', () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            win.confirm(confirmMessage);
          }, 500 );
        });
    });    

    // (2) actual test code
    // -------------------------------------------------------

    cy.get('.btn').click();
    cy.wrap(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      cy.on('window:confirm', msg => {
        try {
          expect(msg).to.eq(confirmMessage);
        } catch ( err ) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve();
      });
      // set a timeout to ensure we don't wait forever
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error('window.confirm wasn\'t called within 4s'));
      }, 4000);
    }), { log: false });

  });
});
```

Comment: So on button click, it goes to a function and the first thing it does is confirm.
``` if (confirm("Some String)) {```
I want to write a test code such that I can test content of the '''Some String'''
But even if the expect fails, the test passes which seems like a bug. Check out the image in the question

Comment: I have also posted this issue to their repository
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6068

Comment: @nimit199 it's not a bug, as I explained in my answer (though the fact it's being reported to Command Log could be thought of as a bug. Not the fact that it's not failing the test). Anyway, I somehow missed you needed to test the message content. I'll update my answer, in a bit.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually quite trivial to solve.

Just pass the Mocha `done` token into the test, and call it in the event handler.

```js
it('Should Get Confirm Message', (done) => {

  // set up the event listener before the action
  cy.on('window:confirm', () => {
    expect(2 + 2).to.equal(5)
    done()                        // if it never calls done(), the test will fail
  })

  // now trigger the window.confirm message
  cy.get('.button').click()
})
```

There's also another pattern using a stub from GlebBahmutov [Window confirm popup](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/recipes/window-confirm.html),

```js
// Cypress auto-accepts the confirmation
cy.contains('Ask user').click()
cy.contains('output', 'Yes').then(() => {
  cy.on('window:confirm', cy.stub().returns(false))
  cy.contains('Ask user').click()
  cy.contains('output', 'No')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/ set a timeout to ensure we don't wait forever
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error('window.confirm wasn\'t called within 4s'));
      }, 4000);
}), { log: false });
```

Is throwing error for me
but on the runner console I see the alert message is captured